# Freeswitch Event Socket

Tags: sockets, voip, freeswitch

I am building a VoIP application using the soft PBX Freeswitch. So far I am able to use event socket library smoothly. However I would like to know how to get the data of a paricular made from code. For instance assuming I have configured an extension in the freeswitch dialplan and someone dials that extension. I would like to get the info related to that call. Please which of the event should I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading on the wiki of Freeswitch I got the answer from this Perl script: https://fisheye.freeswitch.org/browse/freeswitch/libs/esl/perl/server2.pl?r=f3acb355057b3f1c8fd2a3da8749a9674702ecad